# Jquery image/body

Tags: jquery

I currently use:

for my body on load

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('body').hide().fadeIn('8000');
});
</script>
```

However I need some help creating the following:

Body on load show image
after 5 seconds
content shows

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Spending 8 seconds fading in the body, then five seconds to show the images, then show the content. No matter how you do this, it's going to be horrible for users, and most of them will leave your site before it's faded in and ready!

Comment: I think you're looking for .delay(), but what adeneo says still applies

Comment: How about lowering the time 2 seconds for both functions?

Comment: I propose that you have your reasons for wanting this feature.  However, I would suggest adding a cookie or something where users can turn off delays if they do not want to wait for your content to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qzIgn

HTML

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

CSS

```
#foo {
  background-color:red;
  display:none;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#foo').hide('fast').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you  want to display you images after 5 seconds of other content display.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/JygpU/4/

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ncHQiyIktlk/Td3Jd-dHnAI/AAAAAAAAA4Q/BVUcrd2ow9A/s1600/hello.jpg" alt="img1" width="200"/>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){    
    $("#wrapper > :not(img)").hide().fadeIn(8000);
    $("#wrapper > img").hide().fadeIn(20000);
});
```

In this example i am displaying text after 8000 msec & images after 20000 msec.